# How to show and hide keyboard properly in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uiscrollview

I know that his probably is duplicate but I have specific question according my situation.

I must offset keyboard when visible to show `currently edited field` (which is sometimes hidden behind keyboard). I used custom code. It was not working correctly in cases when the next text field is selected or when I have `scroll view` as a container. I change my code as Apple recommends (see [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)).

I have `UIViewController` (`VC`) with embedded `UIScrollView`. My `UITextFields` are inside `scroll view`. I have `header label` in `VC`.

My problems are: 
1. The suggestion element of the keyboard is hiding edited field. I fix this by adding `height` of my `header label`.

2. When I hide keyboard and I am at the **top** or **bottom** of the `scroll view` the big `empty space` is left. Is it possible to calculate `offset` and not to show that `empty space`?

**EDIT:**
The code that I am using is bellow:

```
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
            name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] 
    CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect bkgndRect = activeField.superview.frame;
    bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;
    [activeField.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 
      activeField.frame.origin.y
      -kbSize.height
      +self.lblHeader.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = nil;
}
```

Comment: How can we know what you might be doing wrong when we don't know what you _are_ actually doing?

Comment: My code @matt is exactly as in the link. I can post it here. I don't want to make question very long. I will make edit.

Comment: Perhaps it would help you to see actual working code? https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p522textFieldScrollView/ch23p805textFieldSliding/ViewController.swift That is a downloadable project so you can try it and modify it as you like.

Comment: I notice you are changing the content offset when the keyboard shows, but you are not putting it back again when the keyboard hides. Contrast that with my code, which I pointed you to in my previous comment.

Comment: 10x, @matt. I used your code and it works. But I have only one question. If I am at the last control and I make scroll and select previous control, then after hiding keyboard empty space appears. I suppose that this is because the initial offset is changed. How can I fix this - I mean which parameter to track for scroll offset after showing keyboard?

Comment: Right, you would evidently have to implement the delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll:` and keep track of the offset when it changes.

Comment: Sorry @matt, where can I find examples for iOS 8 of your books in `Objective-C` (if any)? I don't understand `Swift` and the code for moving edited `UITextField` does not work in iOS 8.

Comment: The iOS 8 version of my book is in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I do this without the scroll view

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[info objectForKey: (UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey)] doubleValue];


    CGFloat keyboardTop = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - kbSize.

    CGRect activeFieldFrameClone = activeField.frame;
    CGFloat activeFieldBottom = activeField.frame.origin.y + activeField.frame.size.height;
    if (activeFieldBottom > keyboardTop)
        activeFieldFrameClone.origin.y -= activeFieldBottom - keyboardTop + 30;
        // 30 is Just some offset valur


    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        activeField.frame = activeFieldFrameClone;
    }];

}
```

Basically, check if the active field will be hidden by the keyboard by checking if the bottom of the field will appear lower than the top of the keyboard. If so, move the field up.

on `- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification` I would move it down by whatever value it was moved up by. To do this maybe set a global variable to hold the original frame of the field then set that as the fields new frame.

And maybe register for `keyboardWillShow` instead

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Sorry @Marcus, but I need `Scroll View`, because my content is very tall. My problem is that in Apple's example offset was not stored and when I close keyboard on 1st or last `text field` it removes keyboard and empty space appears before or after all controls, which is not very nice from UI point of view. With @matt example I manage to fix this.